# JFrame Open a file from Chooser

Tags: java, swing

So I have a JFrame and an option that says List Files as a menu, if this is clicked, a window opens up that lets you pick a file. But what I am having problems with is opening the file and loading it into a new window, any help please? My code is below, this is what I've tried, but I seem to be getting errors so I think I did it wrong, also I am getting a syntax error at the end of the ActionPerformed method saying '} expected' but the program runs, not sure what that's about.

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

JMenuBar menubar;
JMenu menu, submenu;
JMenuItem mi;

public MyJFrame(String title) {
    super(title);
    menubar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menubar);
    buildMenu();
}

void buildMenu() {
    menu = new JMenu("File");

    mi = new JMenuItem("New");
    menu.add(mi);
    menubar.add(menu);

    mi = new JMenuItem("List Files");
    menu.add(mi);
    menubar.add(menu);
    menu.addSeparator();
    mi.addActionListener(

            new ActionListener() {
                private Component frame;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent enterPress) {
                    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                    File file1;
                    JFileChooser selection = null;
                    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
                    chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(""));
                    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG) {
                        file1 = selection.getSelectedFile();
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            };

    mi = new JMenuItem("Save As");
    menu.add(mi);
    menubar.add(menu);
    menu.addSeparator();

    mi = new JMenuItem("Close");
    menu.add(mi);
    menubar.add(menu);
}
}
```

Error log when selecting a file from the chooser:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MyJFrame$1.actionPerformed(MyJFrame.java:51)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at     javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at     javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: If you're getting errors and asking questions about them here, it would be wise to show us the full error messages and indicate which lines cause the errors. No sense in making us guess, right?

Comment: OK, now look at the exception stacktrace critically as it tells you which line is throwing a NullPointerException, `MyJFrame.java:51`. So which line is line 51?

Answer (score 2):

You've got ***TWO*** JFileChoosers, and one is null:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(); // *** number 1
File file1;
JFileChooser selection = null;             // *** number 2
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(""));
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG) {
    file1 = selection.getSelectedFile();
} else {

}
```

Don't do that -- use only **ONE** non-null chooser, e.g.,

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(); // *** Keep
File file1;
//   JFileChooser selection = null;        // *** get rid of
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(""));
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG) {
    // file1 = selection.getSelectedFile(); // **** NO ****
    file1 = chooser.getSelectedFile(); // **** YES ****

} else {

}
```

More importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). You should inspect the line carefully that throws it, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: Oh, ok, yeah fixed that, but now when I select a file it doesn't open in a new window, it just goes back to the original JFrame and the chooser closes.

Comment: @DanielD: I'm confused -- what new window are you talking about? I see no code that opens any new window anywhere. As a side note, you don't want to have code that opens lots of windows or that swaps windows as that can annoy the user.

Comment: I need to try and do something like this: http://prntscr.com/70r4kf where the file is selected and it opens in a new window.

Comment: @DanielD: then consider creating a JDialog or JOptionPane (which really is a specialized modal JDialog) and displaying your text in that.